# Visio Add-in find Name of Geometry row

Tags: c#, json, visio

I have made an add-in for Visio that extracts information from Visio shapes to a json file, so that I can recreate Visio drawings in other applications. Now I am working on expanding to getting more than straight lines so I am trying to access the `Name` property of a shape's Geometry.

[image: The Geometry Section of a shape]

I can access the X and Y columns with the following code:

```
var offsetX = shape.CellsSRC[s, r, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visX].ResultIU;
var offsetY = shape.CellsSRC[s, r, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visY].ResultIU;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to find the Name column from the Geometry1 data. As in I want to get "RelLineTo" as output for instance so I know if to draw a straight line or a ellipse for instance in other programs.

UPDATE (code snippet on how I try to translate the suggestion from John:

```
var firstComponent = (short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFirstComponent;
var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePage.CreateSelection(VisSelectionTypes.visSelTypeByLayer, VisSelectMode.visSelModeSkipSuper, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePage.Layers.ItemU[areaLayer]);
foreach (Visio.Shape shape in selection)
{
   for (short s = firstComponent; s < firstComponent + shape.GeometryCount; s++)
      {
         var geoSection = shape.Section[s];
         for (short r = 1; r < geoSection.Count - 1; r++)  // First and last point is always the same
            {
               var pointType = shape.RowType[s, r];
               var pointTyp = Enum.GetName(typeof(Visio.VisRowTags),pointType);
            }
       }
}
```

This is the code I use to find all my X and Y values, apart from that last bit with var pointType/pointTyp. Would be logical if I could get the row-info from within the same for loops, wouldn't it? Can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometry sections have indexed rather than named rows so you have to inspect the [RowType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.rowtype) to find out which one you're dealing with.

Here's an example ([using LINQPad](http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html)) that iterates through the rows in each geometry section of a shape:

```
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();
    var shp = vApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem;
    for (short i = 0; i < shp.GeometryCount; i++)
    {
        var geoSectIdx = (short)(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFirstComponent + i);
        var geoName = $"Geometry{i + 1}";
        $"{shp.NameID}!{geoName}".Dump();
        for (short r = 1; r < shp.Section[geoSectIdx].Count; r++)
        {
            var rowTag = shp.RowType[geoSectIdx, r];
            $"Row.{r} = {Enum.GetName(typeof(Visio.VisRowTags), rowTag)}".Dump();
        }
        "".Dump();
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output (given a shape with two geo sections):

```
Sheet.1!Geometry1
Row.1 = visTagRelMoveTo
Row.2 = visTagRelLineTo
Row.3 = visTagRelLineTo
Row.4 = visTagRelLineTo
Row.5 = visTagRelLineTo

Sheet.1!Geometry2
Row.1 = visTagMoveTo
Row.2 = visTagLineTo
Row.3 = visTagLineTo
Row.4 = visTagLineTo
Row.5 = visTagLineTo
```

Comment: So I get my selection like this, `var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePage.CreateSelection(VisSelectionTypes.visSelTypeByLayer, VisSelectMode.visSelModeSkipSuper, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePage.Layers.ItemU[areaLayer]);` then I iterate through it with this `foreach (Visio.Shape shape in selection)`. Wouldn't that be more or less equal to what you did? As far as I can see your first for-loop goes through each point in a shape? I'll try to update my question with my attempts at translating this, still getting blank results.

Comment: Actually it turns out it's only my last line that doesn't work (see update in question) `var pointTyp = Enum.GetName(typeof(Visio.VisRowTags),pointType);` , but as long as I get the indexes that is just as good. After looking up VisRowTags' `Enum` it only holds values up to 195, and the output I get from RelMoveTo / RelLineTo is 238/239

Comment: Hello Tom, The Rel type segements are there, it's just that the docs haven't been updated.  If you try `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Visio.VisRowTags)).Dump();` you'll get the full set. The Rel row types first appeared in Visio 2013 and, as you've no doubt discovered, expresses a value relative to the owning shape's width or height.  My approach, if I understand your issue correctly, would be to loop through the rows as above and then inspect the X, Y (and A,B,C,D,E) cells depending on which type of row you're addressing.

Comment: Yep, got it all up and running now, I made my own enum instead - as I still have control over which types of rows  I can support on other platforms, found this just as easy. Thanks for this, really struggling to find good documentation on Visio coding.